# C#, WPF Binding, MVVM, INotifyPropertyChanged, Trying to bind instance properties without success

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

Is there a way to put instances of a class, inside another class, and then have the UI update from them with INotifyPropertyChanged? For example these PlayerBaseClass instances PlayerOne and PlayerTwo inside the WhiteJack class, and have them updated in the UI? The only solution that works is to have the context set directly to the instance of the players, and then feed them into the viewmodel which is the main view model..!

```
   class MultipleDataContexts
    {
        public WhiteJack WhiteJackViewModel { get; set; }
        public PlayerBaseClass PlayerOne { get; set; }
        public PlayerBaseClass PlayerTwo { get; set; }
        public MultipleDataContexts()
        {
            PlayerOne = new PlayerBaseClass();
            PlayerTwo = new PlayerBaseClass();
            WhiteJackViewModel = new WhiteJack(PlayerOne, PlayerTwo);
        }
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = new MultipleDataContexts(); // set datacontext for the INotifyPropertyChanged
            InitializeComponent();
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized; //Window to the max.
        }
}
```

Im guessing that this is the only way it will work. The View has to see directly into the set contexts, it cant see into its members. Am I right? Because this did not work:

```
this.DataContext = new WhiteJack();
```

Yeah, no. I cant get the UI to update with binding the textblocks to instances inside WhiteJack, no matter if I set the context to a named instance or not.

Comment: Please can you show the code for the PlayerOne and PlayerTwo properties in the ViewModel.

Comment: @MakerOfTheUnicake: Please don't post code in comments, instead, edit your question with the added code.

Comment: What was the code that didn't work for you? Were you trying to replace one of the players with a new `PlayerBaseClass` instance? Because if that's the case, then those `PlayerOne` and `PlayerTwo` properties should also raise a `PropertyChanged` event - in other words, your `WhiteJack` class should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I was trying to have the instances of the players inside the WhiteJack class. Which didnt work for me. Maybe it didnt work because I never named the instance. Updating with what didnt work.

Comment: Thanks all for trying to help, ive refined my question further and cleaned up the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the DataContext for this (the Window) to a new Instance of WhiteJack(). I'm still not sure exactly what your end goal is but instantiating your two PlayerBaseClass objects in your MultipleDataContexts class will allow you to set the Background using the properties you have created. So set your Color in your ViewModel:

MODEL

```
class MultipleDataContexts
{
    public PlayerBaseClass PlayerOne { get; set; }
    public PlayerBaseClass PlayerTwo { get; set; }
    public MultipleDataContexts()
    {
        PlayerOne = new PlayerBaseClass();
        PlayerTwo = new PlayerBaseClass();
    }
}
```

VIEWMODEL

```
        MultipleDataContexts mdc = new MultipleDataContexts();
        mdc.PlayerOne.TextBlock_Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        mdc.PlayerTwo.TextBlock_Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        this.DataContext = mdc;
```

XAML

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="SeatOne_TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="text" Background="{Binding PlayerOne.TextBlock_Background}" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Opacity="1" Height="155" Width="105" FontFamily="Courier New" Padding="0" Margin="0" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="SeatTwo_TextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="text" Background="{Binding PlayerTwo.TextBlock_Background}" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Opacity="1" Height="155" Width="105" FontFamily="Courier New" Padding="0" Margin="0" />
```

Setting these properties and binding the MultipleDataContexts class to my Window gives me a red and a black textblock background.

Comment: Thanks. I dont know what changed from my own code but I sort of copied you and it works. Maybe I didnt create the instances as properties inside my multipledatacontext. Could that be it? And if so, why does it matter? Why cant I just make ordinary instances of them?

Comment: It's hard to say. I'm not sure what is going on inside your new WhiteJack() ctor. Possible that you weren't setting properties TextBlock_Background with values when you thought/assumed you were?

Comment: It has to do with the getters and setters. Its funny. When i remove the getters and setters. When stepping through the code, it shows correctly the values in xaml view. But it never updates the ui. And when I add them back the xaml is bugged. But the ui updates and everything looks as it should. :) ai think that binding to a field hinders inotifypropertychanged to propagate through. Not sure.